# Mercurial BidMerge message displayed when updating to other branches

Tags: mercurial

When I update to different branches in my repo, sometimes the following message is displayed:

```
note: using 1e30cc4025a0 as ancestor of b9356a6d7187 and 2c4e2c777abe
      alternatively, use --config merge.preferancestor=0275bcbb14e5
```

I found this message to originate from the new BidMerge feature in Mercurial 3.0, but I don't understand why it's showing up on a simple branch change operation. Also, when I add `merge.preferancestor=*` to my hgrc file, it does not suppress the message. Can anyone explain what's going on?